# Effecient Javascript Object filtering using multiple array indexes. How much data before using Node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, filter

I'm looking for both practical, and also theoretical insight about my application.

Take 50,000 js objects, with 5 properties each, structured as

```
0: Object
  CostCenter: "1174"
  Country: "USA"
  Job: "110-Article Search"
  Team: "Financial"
  Username: "anderson"
```

And take 5 respective arrays (one for each object property) such as the 'Country' array

```
4: Array[4]
  0: "Asia Pacific"
  1: "Australia"
  2: "Brazil"
  3: "Canada"
```

What is the most efficient way to filter the 50,000 objects, eliminating all objects which have at least one property which has 0 matches in its respective array.

The max sizes for the arrays are:

```
  CostCenter,  77
  Country,     27
  Job,         27
  Team,        10
  Username,    99
```

My first idea is to loop through the 50,000 objects, and

```
if the 'CostCenter' property === any CostCenter array item,
push the object into a temporary array of objects
```

Which might leave me with only 20,000 objects in the temporary array. Then repeat this process for each property and its respective filtering array, building a new temporary object each time.

Finally this process would leave me with the last array, which would be the resultant data after going through 5 filters.

It takes about 20 seconds for me to download the 18mb JSON file (but I'm okay with that)

...which is exponentially longer than the time it takes my chrome browser on 16gb ram to process the JSON into 50,000 js objects AND loop these objects to dynamically build the filtering arrays with all unique values contained in the JSON.

Is this efficient? It seems very very fast for the amount of data being processed, but I also get the feeling some user environments (like my boss' iPad) may run out of in-browser memory.

What better ways are there?

Should I do this in Node.JS? I am a javascript programmer, so that seems like it may not take too long to learn. Plus Node is super duper hip these days... maybe I should get on with it.

Will some browsers fail to download an 18mb json file? Where can I find info about limits?

Comment: What did you mean by `but something tells me it will only take about 200ms`? Is that how long it is taking right now to filter these objects (which doesn't sound quite right), or is that something you think is easily achievable?

Comment: @Anurag, I removed that paragraph now because it seems irrelevant--but I was just saying the processing I've already done (converting JSON to JS object, and finding the unique param values is incredibly quick now, maybe I shouldn't worry about how I filter, but just get it done.) How long do you think this 5-step filter approach will take Javascript to do?

Comment: @nathanhayfield, Can I create a database in the browser and query that? 
I am trying to find a way to send just a zip of the files (json, js, css, html) and have him extract it on the laptop (or iPad, better yet) even when there is no internet.

Comment: @nathanhayfield I converted big 2-dimensional table XLS to CSV, then to JSON.
I'm just now reading about an in-browser nosql db called TaffyDB which may suit my purposes.

Comment: @nathanhayfield We have been, but the goal is to push the objects into a javascript charting API, as there are more associated parameters such as a date object (x axis), or the cost days wage for this user (y axis)


Excel charts are not as 'pretty'

Comment: alternately, import the xls file into a database with phpmyadmin and then query that database with ajax with the filters you need

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8o5qBEl.png

Comment: you need a database that you can query via ajax calls if you want it fast

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want

```
var arrays = {
    "Country": […],
    …
};
var result = my50000items.filter(function(item) {
    for (var prop in arrays)
        if (arrays[prop].indexOf(item[prop]) == -1)
             return false;
    return true;
});
```

You can optimise this by replacing the `indexOf` call with a faster property lookup. To do so, make:

```
var lookups = {};
for (var prop in arrays) {
    var obj = lookups[prop] = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arrays[prop].length; i++)
        obj[arrays[prop][i]] = true;
}
```

Then you can use

```
var result = my50000items.filter(function(item) {
    for (var prop in lookups)
        if (!lookups[prop][item[prop]])
             return false;
    return true;
});
```